# jQuery Click Event Triggering On Multiple Elements (I only want 1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When my overlay comes up, everything works well, but I added some code to close out the overlay, but this code gets triggered even when I'm just clicking my arrows. The following is the code that's being triggered, which is fine when I'm not clicking the arrows to change the image. But when I click the arrows, the background which is the overlay is also being trigger, so the image is changing but the overlay is also hiding.

```
$('#overlay').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

How can I be able to use the arrows without it also clicking on the background overlay? If you open up the project, you will see what I'm saying.

**To open the project:**
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/rodriguesandrewb/photo_gallery_v1/blob/master/index.html

**To open the repository:**
https://github.com/rodriguesandrewb/photo_gallery_v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `event.stopPropagation()`: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

This prevents the event from bubbling (being triggered by other elements)

Comment: You are the best!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your outter most element is `#overlay`. It means that no matter where you click you'll be always clicking on your `#overlay` element. That is way your callback is being always triggered and closing your image.

To fix your problem and make your image close only when clicking on it you could use:

```
$('#changeImage').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's a ton of code to sort out, so I'm guessing your overlay is

`<div id="overlay" style="display: block;"></div>`

and your `event.target` is deep down inside this:

```
<div class="mainCenter">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="topFixed">
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <ul id="gallery">
            .......
```

I'm not 100% sure where your `event.target` is, (the element you want to click and not everything else). But it's safe to assume that after you click your intended button, the event continues to bubble up the event chain. The event chain is basically your `event.target's ancestors which includes`#overlay` which is at the very top of the event chain.

To prevent event bubbling (btw bubbling is the default behavior but in instances such as your's it's not desired.) try placing `stopPropagation()` after or inside at the end of your event handler.

I wish I could be more specific as to where and how to apply this code as it pertains to your source, but you didn't provide the specific areas that concern your eventListeners, eventHandlers, etc...

The `#overlay` is used in this example but I suggest you use the `event.target` parent instead. The purpose of this code is to accept an event like 'click' on an element (i.e. button) or multiple elements (i.e. buttons) through their mutually shared parent. That's one place to click for potentially several different buttons. At first you'd think that's non-sense and you'd say, "Sure that button is clicked because the parent was clicked, but now everything the parent is chained to will trigger everything else."

That would be correct except we have `stopPropagation();` at the very end of your eventHandler. That will stop propagation of the event bubbling back up the event chain, so there's no more rogue triggers lighting up everywhere. Rogue Triggers® sounds like a great band name. :P

For details and a much better explanation: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm

```
var overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");
theParent.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = e.target.id;
        alert("Hello " + clickedItem);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```